# Get Position of cursor on panel with scrollbars

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll

I've build a simple program (so far) that has a large panel as the "WorkArea" of the program.  I draw a grid onto it, have some functionality that snaps my cursor to closest point on the grid etc.  I have a status bar on the bottom of the window which displays my current position on the panel.  However, regardless of where I've scrolled to (let's say vertical bar is at 10% relative to top and horizontal is 25%) it displays my cursor position with regards to the actual window.

I have a OnMouseMove event that handles this:

```
private void WorkArea_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    GridCursor = grid.GetSnapToPosition(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = grid.GetSnapToPosition(new Point(e.X, e.Y)).ToString();
    Refresh();
}
```

It works as I'd expect giving the points of the cursor, drawing it to the correct place, and so on.  However, if I scroll out, I still get the same readings.  I could be scrolled out half way on the vertical and horizontal scrollbars, put my cursor in the upper left-hand corner, and read a 0,0, when it should be something more like 5000,5000 (on a panel 10k by 10k).

How can one go about getting the absolute position within a panel with respect to its scrollbars?

Comment: So `WorkArea` is a Panel, right? What are `GridCursor`, `grid`, `GetSnapToPosition`. Is `AutoScroll` on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to offset the location by the scroll position:

```
private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
      Point scrolledPoint = new Point( e.X - panel1.AutoScrollPosition.X, 
                                       e.Y - panel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y);

      ..
}
```

Note that the [AutoScrollPosition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscrollposition(v=vs.110).aspx) values are negative..:

> The X and Y coordinate values retrieved are negative if the control
>   has scrolled away from its starting position (0,0). When you set this
>   property, you must always assign positive X and Y values to set the
>   scroll position relative to the starting position. For example, if you
>   have a horizontal scroll bar and you set x and y to 200, you move the
>   scroll 200 pixels to the right; if you then set x and y to 100, the
>   scroll appears to jump the left by 100 pixels, because you are setting
>   it 100 pixels away from the starting position. In the first case,
>   AutoScrollPosition returns {-200, 0}; in the second case, it returns
>   {-100,0}.

Comment: If so happens that you're using a DataGridView, the property you're looking for is HorizontalScrollingOffset and VerticalScrollingOffset

Answer (score -1):

**WinForms:**

The method [Control.PointToClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient.aspx) lets you convert the mouse position relative to the control itself.

```
Point point = grid.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y))
```

**WPF:**

Using [Mouse.GetPosition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.getposition%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) you can get the position of the mouse relative to a specific control:

```
Point position = Mouse.GetPosition(grid);
```

Comment: From the looks of it, that's WPF only.  Is there a way to do this with WinForms?  I saw something to the effect of "Cursor.Current" but I can't seem to find any information as to how to use this object (just trying to get a Point object out of it)

Comment: Ah, missed your winforms tag, added separate solution.